# Java library to generate MSWORD with "restrict editing" field

Tags: java, ms-word, reporting

Is there any Java library allow generating Microsoft Word with "restrict editing" field?
That mean I want to forbid user editing some field with password, while enabling them to edit the others.

I have google around, however, suggestion like apache-poi seems doesn't support the "restrict editing" feature.

I would like to know whether it is possible to do in Java or I will have to get a window server.

---

Finally I don't get a favour library, so i decided to add the protection tag in MS Word's setting.xml by myself, below is the reference link
http://itintheory.blogspot.hk/2012/06/remove-editing-restrictions-in-word.html

Comment: If you have looked at [tag:apache-poi], please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Does apache-poi offer "restrict editing" feature?

Comment: I don't recall; I'm not familiar with the feature.

Comment: thanks you trashgod anyway.

Comment: Without some indication of your findings, this question risks being closed as not constructive. To avoid this, I would encourage you to update your question with any new results from your continued research.

Comment: thanks your advise trashgod, but I just could not from any hints in Google, so I doubt whether we can do it in Java.